# Return 0 if no records found

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to count the number of records in a MS Access database per month. so far I have this query and it works fine;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalproblems,
problems.department,
departments.dname,
month(start_date) AS month
FROM problems
INNER JOIN departments on problems.department = departments.department_id
WHERE year(start_date) = '2014' 
GROUP BY month(start_date), problems.department, departments.dname
```

This returns results like so

```
--------------------------------------------
|totalproblems| department | dname | month |
--------------------------------------------
|10           |1           |bob    |1      |
|3            |2           |sam    |1      |
|8            |3           |mary   |1      |
--------------------------------------------
```

Which is as expected. What I need though is to also return the departments that didn't have any problems recorded like so

```
--------------------------------------------
|totalproblems| department | dname | month |
--------------------------------------------
|10           |1           |bob    |1      |
|3            |2           |sam    |1      |
|8            |3           |mary   |1      |
|0            |4           |sue    |1      |
--------------------------------------------
```

I have tried `NZ(COUNT(*),0) AS totalproblems` which just created another column with the exact same values as totalproblems minus any 0's

I've tried `IIF(ISNULL(totalproblems),0)` which returned an empty column

And I've tried `SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*) AS totalproblems,0)`
Which gives me a `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression`

Not sure what else to try or what I'm doing wrong with what I've tried.

Comment: the INNER JOIN only permits departments that have problems; as shown below you need to reverse the table precedence; FROM departments (so you can list all departments) then LEFT JOIN on problems. see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `outer join`:

```
SELECT COUNT(problems.department) AS totalproblems, problems.department, departments.dname,
       month(problems.start_date) AS month
FROM departments LEFT JOIN
     problems
     on problems.department = departments.department_id
WHERE (year(problems.start_date) = '2014' OR problems.start_date IS NULL)
GROUP BY month(start_date), problems.department, departments.dname;
```

Comment: This still seems to only be returning results for departments that have a problem listed.

Comment: You don't have any rows with `NULL` values for `department` and/or `month`?

Comment: Can't seem to @ ... Ah I see what's happening now. You're correct in that there are departments that have been added in mid year which was throwing me off. Hmm, now I need to figure out a better way of handling this I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalproblems,
departments.department_id,
departments.dname,
month(start_date) AS month
FROM departments
LEFT JOIN problems on problems.department = departments.department_id
WHERE year(start_date) = '2014' 
GROUP BY month(start_date), department_id.department, departments.dname
```

Comment: I see the JOIN has changed to a LEFT but this still only returns results that have had a problem submitted and not 0 for those that haven't.